# Show unique filename only on command grep result

Tags: unix, grep

I'm trying to show only unique filenames when I *grep* a certain string. Currently I'm getting multiple results with the same filename if a certain string appear several times inside a file.

for example:

If I have a string "string12345" and it appears 3 times in several lines inside filename1.txt and appear 3 times in several lines inside filename2.txt as well when I use *grep 'string12345' *.txt* it shows 3 occurrences of filename1.txt and filename2.txt

Now what I'm trying to achieve is to show only 1 occurrence of filename1.txt and filename2.txt. Thank you in advance.

Comment: try with `grep -m1` or if you want only file names, use `grep -l`

Comment: Thanks a lot Sundeep it works

Answer (score 27, accepted):

use the `-l` flag.

test.txt:

```
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
```

Grep search:

```
$ grep ./ -re "Hello"
./test.txt:Hello, World!
./test.txt:Hello, World!
$ grep ./ -re "Hello" -l
./test.txt
```

From the manual:

```
-l, --files-with-matches
              Suppress  normal  output;  instead  print  the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed.  The scanning will stop on the first match.
```